# How to show two complexes in derived categories are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-categories

I am new to derived categories, and I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category, and $A,B$ be objects in it. Let $C^\bullet \in D(\mathcal A)$ such that
> $$H^{-1}(C^\bullet)=A, ~H^{0}(C^\bullet)=B$$
> and all other cohomology groups are trivial. Then, there exists a distinguished triangle with the form
> $$B[-1] \to A[1] \to C \to B$$

The followings are what I have tried:

For any fixed $B[-1]\to A[1]$, the corresponding $C$ comes from the mapping cone. Since $B[-1]\to A[1]$ might not be an honest chain map, we have to find a quasi-isomorphic one:
$$B[-1]\xleftarrow{q.is.} B^\bullet \xrightarrow{f^ \bullet} A[1]$$
and
$$C^\bullet= C(f^\bullet)$$

Since $A[1]$ is only nontrivial at degree $-1$, only $f^{-1}$ is nontrivial. By truncation, one can assume
$B^\bullet$ are zero except at degree $-1,0,1$. Then, $C(f^\bullet)$ has to be as
$$0 \to B^{-1} \xrightarrow{d^{-2}} A\oplus B^0 \xrightarrow{d^{-1}} B^1 \to 0$$
Here $d^{-1}$ is given by
$$(b,a)\mapsto (-d(b),0) $$
and $d^{-2}$ is given by
$$ (b,a)\mapsto (-d(b),f^{-1}(b)) $$
where $d$('s) are the differentials in $B^\bullet$. It remains to show that, by assigning a nice $f^{-1}$, the chain complex $C(f^\bullet)$ is quasi-isomorphic to any two-step complex $C^\bullet$ as discripted in the setting. By definition, we need to first construct a morphism, but I have no idea what how to do this. It would be very nice if anyone could give a hint on this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the truncation functors ? In general, you always have a distinguished triangle $\tau^{\leq i}C\to C\to\tau^{\geq i+1}C\overset{+1}\to$.

Comment: @Roland Yes, ok, I see, thanks a lot. This is quite straightforward. It is just strange to me that the naive computation (like my attempt) is not as clear as I expect. (and sorry for the very late reply)

Comment: You have constructed a complex $C'$ as a cone of some $f:B[-1]\to A[1]$, and then you want a quasi-isomorphism $C'\to C$. Well, first this is not obvious since you don't know what $f$ is, but even if you knew $f$, there may be no quasi-isomorphism $C'\to C$ and instead you would have to construct a zig-zag $C'\leftarrow C''\to C$ which is in general a very complicated task. This is why your attempt is actually not easy at all.